# Retrieving input data into array, but giving every single element a length

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

As the title shows I have a problem that I'm fighting and can't find a solution to it so here I am. Im writing a simple "decision maker" and need to gather the info from the input bar and put it to the empty array. BUT (as you know) typing in the input gives me only a solid string and I need a array of seperated elements (eg. ["pizza", "restaurant", "movies"]. I've tried it with .split() but it only works partways because all of the elements are assingned to the same length.

Is there a function/method to do what I need?

```js
const array = [];
const helpBar = document.querySelector("input");
const answerBar = document.querySelector("h1");

const askHelp = (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    const myArr = helpBar.value.split("");
    array.push(myArr);
    console.log(array);
    helpBar.value = "";
    const arrayRNG = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    document.querySelector("h1").textContent = array[arrayRNG];
  }
};

helpBar.addEventListener("keydown", askHelp);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input" />`enter code here`
  <label for="input"></label>

</form>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: You need to describe better what exact behavior are you after. And for sure splitting it at every character is wrong. And even if you try to split it at space `.split(" ")` what if you have one item that has space inside? I would suggest creating new dynamic inputs for every new item... Or condition the input to have comma for example between items then split it at coma `.split(",")` and trim inputs .

Comment: Also when you split string it creates array no need to push anything into new one... Also why random? And so on...

Comment: ok so I want to have an input where the user can put in some choices that he has a problem to get a decision wich one to choose. next the choices from the input  would be printed out on the screen and randomly chosen one -  decision made for the user.

Answer (score 0):

If I where you id do it similar too this:

This will add new input for every new item on click of button and on another click take all values and pick random one:

```js
const helpBar = document.querySelector("input");
const answerBar = document.querySelector("h1");
const newItem = document.querySelector("#newitem");
const randomize = document.querySelector("#randomize");
const item = document.querySelector(".item");
const items = document.querySelector("#items");

const itemFun = (e) => {
  let itemClone = item.cloneNode(true)
  itemClone.value = ""
  items.appendChild(itemClone);
}

const askHelp = (e) => {
  let res = []
  document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach(item => {
    res.push(item.value)
  });

  var randomItem = res[Math.floor(Math.random() * res.length)];
  answerBar.innerHTML = randomItem
};

newItem.addEventListener("click", itemFun);
randomize.addEventListener("click", askHelp);
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <input type="text" class="item" id="input" />
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" id="newitem">Add new item</button>
<br>
<button type="radom" id="randomize">Randomize</button>
<br>
<h1></h1>
```

Or if you really want to use input event and one input element, set the delimiter as `,` comma for example. And detected if one is present then  split at that mark:

```js
const helpBar = document.querySelector("input");
const answerBar = document.querySelector("h1");

const askHelp = (e) => {

  if (e.target.value.includes(",")) {
    let res = e.target.value.split(",").map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim)
    // this will split at comma and also trim spaces if user has entered

    var randomItem = res[Math.floor(Math.random() * res.length)];
    answerBar.innerHTML = randomItem
  }
};

helpBar.addEventListener("input", askHelp);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="item" id="input" />

<h1></h1>
```